# returning value using ajax in Rails

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and Ruby on rails so if this is very noob question. Please understand me. I have a very basic ajax form

**Ajax**

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/someurl",
  data: $('somedata').serialize(),
  success: function(response){
     alert("<%=@whatever_value%>");
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("Hate this!!!");
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
def someurl

  @whatever_value = Whatevermodel.find(something)
  respond_with(@whatever_value)

end
```

so I am basically trying to use the `@whatever_value` from the `someurl` controller and then want to use the `@whatever_value` in the `view` where the `ajax` is located. I tried `respond_with` but it doesnt really work. Is there anyway I can get the value from the controller and then use the value in the view. If any further information is required to solve the issue, I will add some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's based on the approach that you would want to get your result using the AJAX call. I use the following to achieve what I want most especially when I pass a parameter value to the controller method and get the result back via the call.

```
  // get the textbox value
  var sel_nomen = document.getElementById("id_of_field_to_get_value_from").value;

  // check for null or emptiness
  if (sel_nomen != null || sel_nomen != "") {

    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",
      url: '/application/ajaxsearch/' + sel_nomen, //concatenate the parameter value
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function (data){
        if (data.variable_found == true) {

          // clear field original contents
          document.getElementById('field_to_set_value').value = ""

          // set fields contents
          document.getElementById('field_to_set_Value').value = data.variable_value_from_controller;
          document.getElementById('another_field_to_set_Value').value = data.another_variabls_value_from_controller;

        } else {

          // perform other functions here
        }
      }
    });
```

Note
If your ajax call type is POST {type: 'POST'} and the view action (button click or drop-down change) is not posting a form, then add this line too to avoid errors

```
   $.ajax({   

      beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
      url: '/application/ajaxsearch/' + sel_nomen, //concatenate the parameter value
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function (data){
        // continue like before
      }
    });
```

And in your rails controller or helper method, for example, you can do the following;

```
def ajax_call_method

    categories = Category.select(:all).where("id = ?", params[:id])

    // variable to hold our the dynamic array to be passed as json
    data = nil

    if (categories.length > 0)
        for category in categories do
            data = { :variable_found => true,
                     :variable_value_from_controller => category.field_name,
                     :another_variable_value_from_controller => category.another_field_name 
                    }
        end
    end

    // return the results as in a json format
    render :json => data
end
```

This is my piece of idea and I hope it will serve a purpose. Kindly let me know if there are any errors or another cool way of achieving the same results.

Have fun!!